# Is it possible to find a $3 \times 3$ matrix satisfying $p(t)=t^2+t+1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

Is it possible to find a $3 \times 3$ real matrix satisfying

1) $p(t)=t^2+t+1$

2) $p(t)=t^2+1$

My intuition says no for both the polynomial but how do I prove that?

Comment: Do you by satisfying mean $p(t)=0$

Comment: @Piyush Divyanakar, yes

Comment: Both these equations give complex eigen values, But only two values if you can have $0$ as the third eigen value then it might be possible to have such a $3\times 3$ matrix.

Comment: Real matrix?  Or can it have complex entries?  How about a diagonal matrix with entries $i,i,-i$ for the second.

Comment: Yes, it real matrix , sorry for confusion.

Comment: I assume $p$ is supposed to be the matrix' minimal polynomial, as the characteristic polynomial of a $3\times 3$-matrix has degree 3. Well, do you know a $2 \times 2$-matrix with those minimal/characteristic polynomials? Then take those and add a row and a column of $0$'s.

Comment: A nice idea @TorstenSchoeneberg, but that constant term $+1$, which presumably translates to the identity matrix, will ruin your idea. The zero row/column will be disturbed by that.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. $p(t)$ in both cases has complex conjugate roots, thus, due to the fundamental theorem of algebra, the third eigenvalue $\lambda$ of the original matrix $A$ exists and it must be real. It means that
$$
\exists x\ne 0:\quad Ax=\lambda x,
$$
but 
$$
(A^2+A+I)x= A^2x+Ax+Ix=\lambda^2 x+\lambda x+x=(\lambda^2+\lambda+1)x,
$$
i.e. $\lambda^2+\lambda+1$ (which is $\ne 0$) is an eigenvalue of $A^2+A+I$. This is impossible for $A^2+A+I=0$.